# Is there a maximum file size of an SSH certificate or a maximum number of supported principals

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have an SSH-certificate (`ed25519`) which has a file size of ~ 8.3K and more than 100 SSH principals.

When I tried to view its contents (`ssh-keygen -Lf <FILE_PATH>`) I would receive an invalid-format error.

I was wondering if the openssh implementation of SSH has a maximum file size of an SSH certificate or a maximum number of supported principals.

Comment: if you ever found the answer, do feel free to update or even answer your own question!

Comment: Neither did I get one, nor found one myself. Unfortunately.